# How to write a Query to show multiple output in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables tbl_emp & tbl_EmpSal where Emp_Id is primary_key in tbl_emp and foreign key for tbl_EmpSal as shown below.

```
create table tbl_emp
( Emp_Id int,
Emp_Name Varchar(20)
)

insert into tbl_emp(Emp_Id,Emp_Name)
select 1,'aaa'
union
select 2,'bbb'
union
select 3,'ccc'
union
select 4,'ddd'
```

--select * from tbl_emp

```
create table tbl_EmpSal
(Emp_id int,
EmpSal int)

insert into tbl_EmpSal
select 1,2000
union
select 2,4000
union
select 3,NULL
```

--select * from tbl_EmpSal

Now I want to write the SQL query to show output as below:

```
EMP_Name   EmpSal/Details

aaa     2000

bbb     4000

ccc     NEW JOINEE

ddd         Contractor
```

The output shows that for any given Emp_id in tbl_EmpSal table if EmpSal column is NULL we have to show output as 'NEW JOINEE' in EmpSal/Details column.

And when there is no Row for any given Emp_id in tbl_EmpSal table we have to show output as 'Contractor' in EmpSal/Details column.

Comment: +1 . . . If both Aaron and I find the question interesting enough to answer, then it is not worth a downvote.  And, you did include code to generate the tables that you want for the question.

Comment: @Gordon who knows, people down-vote for all kinds of reasons, but there are plenty of potential reasons someone would have down-voted this post, particularly in its original form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.Emp_Name,
  [EmpSal/Details] = CASE 
    WHEN s.EmpSal > 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), s.EmpSal)
    WHEN s.Emp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'NEW JOINEE'
    WHEN s.EmpSal IS NULL THEN 'Contractor'
  END
FROM dbo.tbl_emp AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_EmpSal AS s
ON e.Emp_id = s.Emp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather tricky question.  It involves both a `left outer join` and distinguishing between a `NULL` value that is found and a missing match:

```
select Emp_Name,
       (case when es.Emp_Id is NULL then 'Contractor'
             when es.EmpSal is NULL then 'NEW JOINEE'
             else cast(EmpSal as varchar(255))
        end) as EmpSal_Details
from tbl_emp e left outer join
     tbl_EmpSal es
     on e.Emp_id = es.Emp_Id;
```